# wx.StaticBox doen't work properly

Tags: python, wxpython

I am learning wxPython library and now I am trying `wx.StaticBox` with `wx.StaticBoxSizer`. As written in the documentation https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.StaticBoxSizer.html#wx-staticboxsizer, it's recommended to add elements to staticbox as its children. And I do evertything, seemingly, like in the example in the documentation, but the result is a bunch of overlayed elements without even a staticbox-line. What is wrong and how do I do a normal layout in `wx.StaticBox`?
Here is the code of initializing the main frame:

```
def Init_UI(self):
    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    sb = wx.StaticBox(panel, label='Personal Info')
    sbs = wx.StaticBoxSizer(sb, wx.VERTICAL)

    gender = wx.StaticText(sb, label='Your gender')
    male = wx.RadioButton(sb, label='Male', style=wx.RB_GROUP)
    female = wx.RadioButton(sb, label='Female')

    sbs.AddMany([
        (gender, ),
        (male, ), 
        (female, ),
        ])
```

Comment: Do you mean to be adding the elements to the `StaticBoxSizer`, or do you mean to add it to the `StaticBox`?

Comment: in `StaticBox`, but as I know, it's done via `StaticBoxSizer` (see the first example in the documentation), isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it looks that way.  I'm just curious to see what happens if you add it to the `StaticBox`.

Comment: it says that it hasn't such a method

Comment: I have tried setting a sizer (`wx.BoxSizer` in my case) to a `wx.Panel` and then adding to that sizer my `wx.StaticBoxSizer`, which worked. I have some guesses why it is that, but now do not know fundamental reasons. Would be thankful for someone to clarify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't `set` the sizer for the panel but also take note that certain Themes for your desktop (on Linux at least) do not show static boxes. So if a box isn't drawn, test with another Theme. (Preferences->Appearance)

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        sb = wx.StaticBox(panel, -1, label='Personal Info')
        sbs = wx.StaticBoxSizer(sb, wx.VERTICAL)

        gender = wx.StaticText(sb, label='Your gender')
        male = wx.RadioButton(sb, label='Male', style=wx.RB_GROUP)
        female = wx.RadioButton(sb, label='Female')

        sbs.AddMany([
            (gender, ),
            (male, ),
            (female, ),
            ])
        panel.SetSizer(sbs)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'A Static box')
        frame.Show()
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]